# O que são e como identificar subdomínios em DDD?

Tags: arquitetura-de-software, ddd

Estudando DDD encontrei a ideia de subdomínio. Pelo que entendi, um subdomínio é um subconjunto do espaço do problema que a aplicação tem que lidar, ou seja, um subconjunto do domínio. Pelo que li existem três tipos de subdomínios: "core", "supporting" e "generic".

Essa é a primeira parte que não entendi muito bem. Por que fazer essa distinção entre três tipos de subdomínios e o que cada um representa? Não entendi muito bem como diferenciar "core" e "supporting". Generic eu entendi mais ou menos como sendo algo que está envolvido no domínio mas que não é especifico daquele problema, mas não sei se é bem isso.

Mas a principal dúvida mesmo é como identificar os subdomínios. O que quero dizer é: o que devemos considerar na hora de fazer esse particionamento do domínio pra não acabar fazendo uma divisão absurda que só vai complicar mais as coisas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## O que são subdomínios em DDD

Quando você **separa o domínio** entre aquilo que é a **motivação da aplicação** e aquilo que é, por assim dizer, **auxiliar**, você tem o ***core domain*** e os ***generic subdomains***; sendo que estes últimos são os subdomínios. (Em DDD não existe o artefato *"supporting domain"*).

## *Core domain* e *generic subdomains*

Você já deve ter ouvido falar em ***core business***.

Toda empresa faz muitas coisas importantes, mas nem tudo que é importante faz parte do *core business* da empresa.

**O *core business* é a idéia básica e central de uma empresa.** Um exemplo simples: em uma fábrica de carros, embora a disposição dos carros finalizados no pátio seja importante para os negócios por conta dos impactos causados em logística, a tarefa de dispor os carros no pátio não faz parte do *core business* da empresa. A fábrica pode terceirizar a disposião dos carros a uma empresa de logística mas não vai terceirizar a própria fabrição dos carros.

Esta analogia pode ser usada para compreender o **core domain**:

> **CORE DOMAIN** é a motivação do projeto ou solução de software.

É importante identificar e separar claramente o *core domain* porque é ele quem mais agrega valor, portanto deve ter prioridade nos investimentos - por exemplo: deve contar com os principais desenvolvedores do time, suas necessidades de *refactoring* tem prioridade às demais, dificilmente suas funções serão exercidas por frameworks de terceiros.

E o que não faz parte do *core domain* vai então constituir os *generic subdomains*.

> **GENERIC SUBDOMAINS** abrangem as demais regras de negócio ou modelos que não fazem parte do *core domain*.

As partes do modelo que adicionam complexidade mas não ajudam a expressar o *core domain* acabam contribuindo para dificultar o seu entendimento, desviando a foco daquilo que é mais importante.

Um exemplo do que decorre da não separação explícita entre *core* e *generic subdomains* é o projeto ter os melhores desenvolvedores do time focados em fazer frameworks genéricos de alta tecnologia (mas que não são a alma do projeto) ou modelando partes menos importantes do sistema como cadastros básicos, enquanto profissionais ainda não preparados escrevem a regra de negócio essencial com um "design" que pode trazer sérios riscos ao sucesso do projeto.

Veja que estamos restritos à regras de negócio. Em um sistema que persiste dados do *core domain* em um banco relacional, a persistência dos dados é fundamental, mas não é nem *core domain* nem *generic subdomain*, pois ela faz parte da *infraestrutura* e não do *domain*.

## Como identificar subdomínios em DDD

Não é tarefa trivial. Se não tomar cuidado, todas as regras de negócio relevantes integrarão o *core domain* e os *generic subdomains* terão apenas as regras que nem deveriam ter sido implementadas (tipo uma lixeira de trabalho inútil).

O que vai ajudar a identificar o *core* é a definição de que ele é **pequeno**. Outra definição é que o *core domain* é o que **mais entrega valor ao cliente** do projeto, então a identificação pode ser por comparação.

Mas a grande chave mesmo é a definição da **Visão do Domínio**. A Visão descreve a motivação do projeto ou da solução de software e ela é realmente muito pequena, cabe em uma página. Então se um assunto não está diretamente referenciado pela Visão, ele não pertence ao *core domain*.

Para não correr o risco de fazer separações de domínio que podem mais complicar do que ajudar, não faça esta divisão sem o devido conhecimento de causa, ou seja, não tente prevê-la. O conhecimento do domínio é aprofundado durante o projeto, então a noção do que é *core* e do que é *generic* também vai evoluir ao longo do projeto; e a separação não acontece apenas uma vez, mas sim durante todo o ciclo de vida do sistema através da refatoração dos modelos.

## Conclusão

Em DDD existem o **core domain** e os **generic subdomains**, sendo que o *core* compreende a motivação principal da aplicação, a qual pode ser obtida da **Visão do Domínio**, e os *generic* compreendem os modelos que dão suporte ao *core*.

A importância de separá-los é, dentre outras, diminuir a complexidade do *core domain* e ajudar a priorizar os investimentos (quem faz o que, o que deve ser feito primeiro, o que pode ser terceirizado...).

Comment: Obrigado @Caffé, eu estava vendo o livro do Vaughn Vernon e lá ele da um exemplo de um sistema de vendas. Ele divide o domínio em subdomínios "Catalogo de Produtos", "Pedidos", "Cobrança", "Envio" e "Estoque". Então a ideia é fazermos uma divisão do domínio em partes mais simples e entre elas identificar aquilo que é o principal do negócio, que seria o core? E então aprimorar o que entendemos como core refatorando com o tempo?

Comment: @Leonardo Eu não li este livro então não sei a idéia dele. Apenas lendo este seu curto exemplo, eu posso dizer também que isso são *models* de um domínio e não *subdomínios*, que são coisas de diferentes. Um domínio pode ter vários *models* segundo o conceito de *bounded context*. E um domínio também pode ser dividido em *core domain* e *generic subdomains*, sendo que o *core* pode ter vários *models* e cada *generic* também pode ter vários *models*. Se estes forem *models*, eu posso dizer que "Pedidos" e "Cobrança" são o *core domain* e que os demais integrarão 1 ou mais *generic subdomains*.

Answer (score 1):

## Por que fazer essa distinção entre três tipos de subdomínios e o que cada um representa?

A distinção entre os subdomínios significa divisão de escopos de partes do domínio.

O subdomínio "core" é a parte mais interna do domínio, é o subdomínio que contém as partes mais importantes do domínio como um todo.

O subdomínio "supporting" é a conexão entre os subdomínios "core' e "generic", providenciando a comunicação entre ambos.

O subdomínio "generic" é a parte genérica entre os vários problemas que podem existir no domínio.

Para fazer a partição dos domínios, é necessário identificar:

1. O que outros produtos poderiam usar como informações? Dados como documentos pessoais, por exemplo.
2. O que é realmente vital para o funcionamento do aplicativo? Suas principais funções? Seus requisitos funcionais?
3. Como você vai comunicar os requisitos funcionais com os dados?