# Como implementar regras de negócio ou regras de sistema usando Domain Driven Design no C#?

Tags: c#, ddd

Estou tendo dúvidas em como poder separar regras de negócio de regras de sistema com o DDD.

Se eu tenho por exemplo uma Classe `Usuario` com `id`,`nome`,`login`,`senha` como propriedades. Uma regra de domínio seria requerer uma senha para o usuário, que seria uma `specification` dentro da camada de domínio.

Agora, uma regra que seria: para o usuário cadastrar a senha, ele deve inserir duas vezes para confirmar a senha digitada:

Isso seria uma regra dentro da minha camada de domínio? Ou ficaria em outra camada?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A regra em si ficaria na classe `Usuario`. Mas você não precisaria fazer a validação da senha do `Usuario` duas vezes na classe de domínio, pois quando diz:

> Agora, uma regra que seria: para o usuário cadastrar a senha, ele deve
>   inserir duas vezes para confirmar a senha digitada

Isto está mais para uma validação no front-end, sem necessidade de também fazê-la no back-end (na classe `Usuario`).

Continuando a resposta, no seu caso, você precisa primeiro verificar onde colocar sua classe `Usuario` dentro do sistema.

No contexto do DDD, ela poderia ficar em um projeto de *Domain* (classes de domínio), no contexto do Usuario (UsuarioCtx) e dentro de uma agregação de Usuario (UsuarioAgg):

```
Projeto.Domain/UsuarioCtx/UsuarioAgg/Usuario.cs
```

A regra poderia estar em um método dentro desta classe. Mas, no entanto, até chegar na sua classe de domínio, é esperado que ela passe por alguma classe de Controller. Mas, é preciso também separar corretamente seu projeto para abrigar esta classe de controller. Uma possibilidade é ela estar em um outro projeto de *Interface*. Se estiver usando REST, uma sugestão seria:

```
Projeto.Interface/Services/Rest/UsuarioCtx/UsuarioController.cs
```

Lá, finalmente, você poderia ter um serviço para cadastrar a senha. Como falei anteriormente, você pode chamar este serviço depois que validar, no front-end, se o usuário inseriu 2 senhas iguais. Validado isto, chame um serviço REST correto (um `PUT`, pois é uma atualização), como um `cadastrarNovaSenha` (nome do método na classe, não do serviço!) no seu `UsuarioController`.

No `UsuarioController`, faça outras validações pertinentes que, de preferência, possam estar na classe de domínio do Usuario (exemplo: verificar se a senha é igual cadastrada é igual a nova senha, comparando o *hash*). Tomando sempre cuidado, é claro, de não ficar passando classes de *Repository* para dentro da sua classe de domínio para realizar buscas...

Se quiser mesmo fazer a validação no back-end das senhas iguais do formulário, pode usar um método simples como este no `Usuario.cs`, sendo chamado do `UsuarioController.cs`:

```
public bool VerifySenhasIguais(String senhaNova)
{
     //TODO comparação com a senha atual
}
```

Feito as validações necessárias, atualize o usuário com a nova senha e salve novamente. Esta etapa tem mais detalhes, mas creio que a pergunta sua não englobe isto.

Lembrando que não estou entrando no mérito da discussão de que precisa de tudo isto para conseguir o que quer, mas estou dando um exemplo de como poderia ser.

Comment: eu entendi o que você quis dizer perfeitamente, é exatamente como eu achava que pensava, ainda que a forma que você respondeu esteja diferente do ponto de vista da pergunta, deu pra entender o que você quis dizer com a separação dos serviços implementações, interfaces, e também o cuidado com os repositórios, pois a camada de domínio só possui interfaces de repositórios e não as classes concretas propriamente ditas....

Answer (score 4):

Isso não é regra de domínio então não deveria residir na camada de domínio.

**Login e detalhes de login são [regras de aplicação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/117705/14584) e não de negócio.**

Segurança, de maneira geral, são requisitos não funcionais (a não ser que trate-se justamente de um software de segurança, como uma ferramenta de integração com o Active Directory).

> Em DDD, a regras de domínio são definidas por especialistas no negócio. Você consegue visualizar um especialista no negócio falando sobre Contas a Pagar, por exemplo, e ao mesmo tempo pedindo para ter que preencher dois campos de senha em vez de um?

Na verdade o especialista em negócio sequer vai pedir uma tela de login. Ele preferiria nem ter que fazer login se lhe fosse permitido.

> Login e detalhes de como logar no sistema definitivamente não são regras de negócio, portanto em DDD isso não pertence à camada de domíno.

**Você deve escrever estas regras na camada de aplicação.**

Eventualmente **autorização*** pode ser uma regra de domínio se a separação de deveres for essencial para o negócio (algumas vezes podem ser inclusive exigências regulatórias).

<sub>Autorização* é a definição de como um usuário pode interagir com o sistema no sentido do que ele pode ver e do que ele pode modificar.</sub>

Nestes casos, se o projeto prevê [*core domains* e *generic subdomains*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/49904/14584), a autorização pertence a um *generic subdomain*.

Answer (score 3):

Esse exemplo fica um pouco complicado de colocar na sua classe de domínio pois você teria que ter duas propriedades referente a senha na sua classe, o que ficaria estranho. Nesse caso específico você poderia colocar essa regra em um outro lugar.

Um exemplo mais claro seria algo como verificar se o cliente já pagou todas as compras anteriores para concluir uma nova compra, ficaria algo como abaixo:

```
public class Cliente
{
    public ICollection<Compra> Compras { get; set;}
}

public class Compra
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Produto> Produtos { get; set;}
    public Cliente Cliente { get; set; }
    public bool Pago { get; get; }

    public void Fechar()
    {
        if (Cliente.Compras.Any(c => c.Id != this.Id && c.Pago == false))
            throw InvalidOperationException("Não é possível concluir a compra pois conta pagamentos em aberto");

        //TODO: código de fechamento de vendas
    }
}
```