# O que é Regras de aplicativo e quais são as diferenças em relação às Regras de negócio?

Tags: mvc, engenharia-de-software

Segundo a definição deste [site](https://dextra.com.br/pt/blog/requisito-ou-regra-de-negocio/):

> **Regra de negócio** é o que define a forma de fazer o negócio, refletindo
>   a política interna, o processo definido e/ou as regras básicas de
>   conduta.  Ou seja, é um conjunto de instruções que os usuários já
>   seguem e que o sistema a ser desenvolvido deve contemplar.

Em projetos que implementam o padrão MVC todas as regras de negócio são implementadas no Model, entretanto, lendo a [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/94266/27190) do usuário [Caffé](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/14584/caff%C3%A9) eu me deparei com o termo *Regras de aplicativo*, e percebi na resposta que as *regras de aplicativo* são tratadas de uma forma diferente das regras de negócio.

A minha duvida é a respeito do que é em si as *Regras de aplicativo* e quais as diferenças dela em relação com as regras de negócio?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## As camadas de um sistema

Um software ordinário, como um aplicativo Web, por exemplo, pode ser dividido em algumas camadas conceituais:

- **Interface**
- **Aplicativo**
- **Negócio**
- **Infraestrutura**

Há sistemas em que algumas destas camadas se confundem um pouco, há outros em que elas estão muito bem delineadas e há outros ainda que segregam algumas destas camadas em mais camadas; e os nomes das camadas também podem variar. Mas estas 4 camadas são o básico de um sistema que busca separação de responsabilidades.

## Camada de Negócio

> Nesta camada está o código que representa os conceitos do negócio e é onde o estado do negócio é manipulado.

Se o sistema é especializado em controlar uma conta corrente bancária, por exemplo, é no código desta camada que são feitos débitos e créditos numa conta, é nesta camada que o saldo  da conta é calculado, e é aqui que reside o código que não permitirá um débito maior do que o saldo disponível.

## Camada de Aplicativo

> O código nesta camada recebe requisições da camada de interface e coordena os componentes da camada de Negócio para que processem estas requisições.

Seguindo com o  exemplo de controle de conta corrente bancária, o usuário informa os dados de um pagamento numa página do internet banking (a página pertence à camada Interface) e clica em "enviar". Esta requisição será recebida por um código da camada de aplicativo, que por sua vez sabe qual componente de negócio é responsável por processar a ordem de pagamento.

Depois de invocar o componente de negócio passando os dados de pagamento, a camada de aplicativo devolve para o usuário uma página informando o sucesso da operação, ou uma outra página informando o erro.

Este conhecimento de qual página devolver para o usuário é um exemplo de regra de aplicativo.

Digamos que um novo requisito determine que quando uma ordem de pagamento for recusada por falta de saldo o usuário seja informado do seu saldo disponível. Observe que nada mudará na camada de negócio - ela continuará controlando a conta corrente do mesmo jeito que sempre fez.

Já a camada de aplicativo, que antes simplesmente devolvia uma página com o erro, agora deverá primeiro obter o saldo disponível e devolver então uma página diferente, a qual mostrará também o valor do saldo.

> O requisito *"Quando o pagamento for recusado por falta de saldo, mostrar para o usuário o seu saldo disponível"* constitui uma regra de aplicativo.

## Diferença entre regras de negócio e regras de aplicativo

Em um sistema onde os conceitos estão separados, a camada de negócio sabe **como** se resolve um problema e a camada de aplicativo sabe apenas **quem** (qual componente de negócio) resolve o problema.

A camada de aplicativo tem pouco código e nenhum conhecimento de negócio - ela não sabe como se processa um pagamento, ela só sabe quem é que pode fazer isso. Ela não conhece as restrições que podem impossibilitar o processamento, ela só sabe o que fazer com alguns dos erros devolvidos pelo processamento.

A camada de negócio muda o estado do sistema de diversas maneiras para resolver um problema, e entrega informações sobre este estado. A camada de aplicativo não conhece o estado do sistema - ela precisa perguntar para a camada de negócio.

> A camada de aplicativo define o fluxo de interações do usuário.

O fluxo abaixo é um exemplo de **regra de aplicativo:**

- **1)** Ordenar ao componente de negócio que processe o pagamento.
- **2)** Se o componente de negócio retornar sucesso, redireciona o usuário para a página de sucesso.
- **3)** Se o componente de negócio retornar erro:
- **3.1)** Se o erro é saldo insuficiente, obtém do componente de negócio o saldo disponível, mostra o erro e o saldo.
- **3.2)** Se o erro for outro qualquer, simplesmente mostra o erro.

> A camada de negócio define o fluxo de solução do problema.

O fluxo abaixo é um exemplo de **regra de negócio:**

- **1)** Valida os dados da ordem de pagamento.
- **2)** Verifica pelo horário se a ordem pode ser processada imediatamente ou se terá que esperar o próximo dia útil.
- **3)** Verifica se há saldo disponível.
- **4)** Debita da conta o valor do pagamento.
- **5)** Envia o pagamento para a fila para ser executado.

## Outro exemplo

Só para dar uma luz de que **regras de aplicativos não se limitam a determinar a navegação do usuário em um sistema Web**:

Eu trabalhei em um sistema que executava diversos processos de negócio.

Havia processos que eram ativados por recebimento de mensagens de um sistema de filas de mensagens (Message Queueing) e havia outros processos que eram executados a intervalos regulares, de tantos em tantos segundos.

Neste caso, os mecanismos que determinavam o momento da execução do processo eram regras de aplicativo, e os processos em si eram regras de negócio.

**Mais exemplos** de regras que geralmente são de aplicativo: autenticação, autorização, gestão de licenças, exportação de arquivos, sanitização de entradas do usuário, conversão de tipos de dados entrados pelo usuário, customização da apresentação conforme papel do usuário, integrações entre sistemas.

Comment: Esta camada de aplicativo pode ser implementada em uma aplicação Desktop ou ela é mais aproveitada em aplicações WEB?

Comment: @drmcarvalho Sim, pode. Como são camadas conceituais, podem sim ser implementadas independentemente das camadas físicas da arquitetura. Uma aplicação desktop ou mesmo mobile complexa pode se beneficiar desta separação de responsabilidades em camadas conceituais.