# Qual a diferença entre lógica de domínio e lógica de aplicação?

Tags: java, mvc

Como saber se devo colocar o método na própria classe ou no BO da classe ? Quando saber a diferença de lógica de domínio e lógica de aplicação?
Obs.: fiquei com a dúvida depois de [ler este artigo](https://robsoncastilho.com.br/2016/03/10/logica-de-negocio-vs-logica-de-aplicacao/)

Comment: O que é "BO da classe"?

Comment: Relacionado: [O que é Regras de aplicativo e quais sãos as diferenças em relação com as Regras de negócio?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/117697/91)

Answer (score 1):

No DDD, nós temos as classes de domínio, que são nossas entidades, nossos objetos, e temos também as classes de serviços.

A classe de domínio é responsável por atender o negócio, é onde possuí validações da entidades, ou alguns métodos que não requerem acesso a repositório, não fazem chamadas pro banco de dados.

A classe de serviço, é responsável por delegar, ou seja "servir" é nela que mandará a entidade fazer a verificação e após o retorno, se der tudo certo é ela que vai delegar o método de salvar no repositório por exemplo.

Tem um slideshare que é bem mastigado, e vale a pena conferir.

https://pt.slideshare.net/rponte/entendendo-domaindriven-design

Espero ter ajudado.